# Path class from stdlib has no function "of"

Tags: kotlin, ktor

In this code, as in [this example](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/blob/2.0.3/codeSnippets/snippets/jte/src/main/kotlin/com/example/Application.kt), I try to configure `resolver` via `DirectoryCodeResolver`, but its parameter `Path.of("somePath")` is incorrect, there is no such function.

`Path` is from `java.nio.file.Path`, but there is no `of()`. Maybe, some file defines an extension for `Path` class?

```
package com.example

import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import com.example.plugins.*
import gg.jte.TemplateEngine
import gg.jte.resolve.DirectoryCodeResolver
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.jte.*
import java.nio.file.Path

fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0") {
        install(Jte) {
            val resolver = DirectoryCodeResolver(Path.of("html"))
            templateEngine = TemplateEngine.create(resolver, gg.jte.ContentType.Html)
        }
        configureRouting()
    }.start(wait = true)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.nio.file.Path` from **Java 11** onwards has the **`static Path of​(String first, String... more)`** method ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...))). It could be possible that you're using a lower Java version and hence not able to find that method in the standard lib.

Try upgrading your Java version and you should be able to use the method `Path.of("html")` as shown in the example.